# SQLite3 C++ Column value wont increment by 1

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a column in one of my tables I'm trying to update via the UPDATE query in sqlite3 in C++. **Using v3.8.10.2** amalgation of sqlite3.

I can set this value to whatever value I want, however I cannot **increment it**.
The value starts at 0. Once I increment it, **it increments to 1.** Afterwards, if I try to increment it again, **it does not increment and it stays at 1.**
The same goes if I replace the value 1 with something like 8. It stays at 8, doesn't go any higher (even though it should go to 16).

```
char* query = "UPDATE THETABLE SET ATTEMPTS = ATTEMPTS + 1 WHERE TESTFIELD = 'Hello';"
int error = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), NULL, 0, &errMsg);

if(error != SQLITE_OK){
    //This doesn't happen, error is = to SQLITE_OK
    cout << "SQL Error: " << error << " message: " << errMsg << endl;
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;
}

cout << "Updated value!" << endl;
```

I used the exact same query via the command prompt console in Windows, it works, it increments. In C++, it stays at 1. Why?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried this query:

> "UPDATE THETABLE SET ATTEMPTS = +1 WHERE TESTFIELD = 'Hello';"

Same thing, it's stuck at 1. Doesn't go any higher.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the schema for that column:

> "ATTEMPTS INTEGER DEFAULT 0,"

Is this a bug in the sqlite3 C++ implementation?

Comment: What's the definition for this column? Setting to `+1` has the effect of setting it to one, not adding one to it.

Comment: Updated first post with my schema.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error on subsequent updates?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.
If I change the value from "1" to "8" though for example, it stays at 8 doesn't go any higher (even though it should be at 16).

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Are you able to reproduce that problem on other columns or other tables?

Comment: Same problem. Doesn't work on any table or column.
Only thing I can try to do is retrieve the value via another query and just set it to that value + 1.

Comment: Something tells me your SQLite library is broken then. Try reinstalling or test on a different machine. Here's a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7a035/1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78573/discussion-between-joe-bid-and-tadman).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was when I was initially adding a row, I was doing an:

> INSERT OR REPLACE

I did not set the value for the field, I had thought it wouldn't get touched but it did, it got set to the default value of 0.

I changed it to:

> INSERT OR IGNORE

and it works now.

Comment: That would have that effect, but you didn't include anything like that in your question. `REPLACE INTO` nukes out a row and will replace all columns regardless of which are specified.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think the way the data is being added into the table would be the reason for this.